# Do I always need lines() with plot()?

Tags: r, plot, lines

When I use `plot()` to plot a time serious variable, it only shows dots. I use second code, `lines()`, to link all the dots. Is this really necessary? Or I did something wrong...

The data is as following. I use the `plot()` and `lines()` to draw the graph to see the trend.

```
YYYYMM<-c("200907","200908","200909","200910","200911","200912","201001","201002","201003","201004","201005","201006","201007","201008","201009","201010","201011","201012","201101","201102","201103","201104","201105","201106")
a<-c(1158,1455,1134,1371,1352,1277,1408,1270,1000,1462,1419,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
a_number_trend<-data.frame(YYYYMM,a)
a_number_trend

plot(a_number_trend$YYYYMM,a_number_trend$a,las=2,type="l",col="blue")
lines(a_number_trend$YYYYMM,a_number_trend$a,las=2,type="l",col="blue")
```

The plot is like this at beginning.
[image]

Then become this.
[image]

But I want the line only without the short bar. Or to change the short bars into points.

Comment: It is because YYYYMM variable is a factor. Change it to character and see.

Comment: You can do that by `data.frame(YYYYMM, a, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`.

Comment: You can't plot against a character variable

Comment: There is an ordering to character variable. There is not one to factors. As for plotting character variable, it does, but just as with factors, a 'series' plot like this is not meaningful. Correct way is to have a date format for that column. It can be converted to it as well.

Comment: You can only by chance plot against a character variable if it happens to also be able to be converted via `as.numeric` - `plot(as.character(1:10), 1:10)` works but `plot(letters[1:10], 1:10)` fails. And you can even get weirder results when it mixes - `plot(c("1","2","c","d"), 1:4)`. It isn't a good idea, but I agree that converting it to a formal date object is the way to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert your `YYYYMM` column to an actual R `?Date` object. Then you can get everything lining up properly:

```
a_number_trend$date <- as.Date(
  paste0(a_number_trend$YYYYMM,"01"),
  format="%Y%m%d"
)

plot(a ~ date, data=a_number_trend, type="l", xaxt="n", ann=FALSE)
```

The below axis is not stricly necessary (remove `xaxt="n"` above if you want the default Date axis calculations instead).

```
axis.Date(
  1,
  at=seq(min(a_number_trend$date), max(a_number_trend$date), by="1 month"),
  format="%Y%m",
  las=2
)
```

Comment: Thanks @thelatemail !! I learn a lot from your solution. It totally works. Thank you again.